# Game Theory Question

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, game-theory

### |

### |     |Adv| ---------|N\A|

### Adv| 300,300     | 900,0          |

### N\A| 0,900     | 700,700           |

Player 1= Pepsi

Player 2= Coke

A) Solve for the pure strategy Nash equilibrium

B) Is this game a prisoner's Dilema?

C) Is there a cooperative equilibrium? If so, what is it?

D) Does coke have a dominant strategy? Does Pepsi?

### My Attempt

---

### |     |Adv| ---------|N\A|

### Adv| (300),(300)     | (900),0          |

### N\A| 0,(900)     | 700,700           |

A) Nash Equilibrium: (Adv, Adv)

B) Not sure how to answer this

C) Yes. If they both got in contact and made the option to not advertise

D)

I would appreciate some help!

Comment: You need to put in more effort. What exactly are you having trouble with? Simply writing a few sentences doesn't really help. I'd also reccomend cleaning up your formatting a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple hints for the two that you haven't answered:

The prisoner's dilemma is characterized by the inability to sustain the Pareto optimal payoff as a Nash Equilibrium due to the existence of a profitable deviation for both players. Each player has a dominant strategy to "Defect" and so the unique Nash Equilibrium is one where both players "Defect". Does that hold here?

A (possibly mixed) strategy $a$ (weakly) dominates another strategy $b$ for a given player $i$ if player $i$ (weakly) prefers playing $a$ to $b$ for any strategy vector of the other players. In your case, there is just one other player, $j$, and so $i$ simply has to prefer $a$ to $b$ for any strategy played by player $j$.

You just need to see if that holds for your two players.